# Is there a package that displays a terminal screen with code with listings or minted?

Tags: listings, packages, minted

I search a LaTeX package which show code inside a terminal image, where I could use listings or minted.

If this not possible I have to build it by myself and will it post here.

Comment: Perhaps `tcolorbox` package and its libraries `listings`, `listingsutf8` and `minted`? In the manual there are some examples that look just like a terminal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
\usepackage{fancyvrb,minted,tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,breakable}
\tcbuselibrary{minted}

\definecolor{terminalColor}{RGB}{38,50,56}
\definecolor{Button1}{RGB}{254,94,86}
\definecolor{Button2}{RGB}{254,188,45}
\definecolor{Button3}{RGB}{38,202,59}

\begin{tcblisting}{listing engine=minted,minted style=native,
    minted language=python,enhanced,
    colback=terminalColor,colframe=terminalColor,listing only, title=\tikz {
        \node[circle,fill=Button1,inner sep=3pt] (c) at (0,0){};
        \node[circle,fill=Button2,inner sep=3pt] (c) at (0.5,0){};
        \node[circle,fill=Button3,inner sep=3pt] (c) at (1,0){};
    } ~~~~~~Terminal}
    >>> a = [1, 2, 3]
    >>> b = a
    >>> b.append(4)
    >>> b
    [1, 2, 3, 4]
\end{tcblisting}
```

[image: Exmaple image]

Comment: Looks a bit Mac-specific :) but nice solution!

Comment: Thanks. I have been inspired by https://carbon.now.sh/. It would be nice to have this also for windows linux and macOS terminals.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this example. Would you please show the preamble you used?

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL I add the imports. Please don't forget to use ``-shell-escape`` and you have to install ``python`` and ``pygments``.

Comment: Thank you very much! Works perfectly! A beautiful implementation too!