Help Adding Mac-style Circles to a tcbox in LaTeX
I hope you're doing well. My name is Mario Gómez Cano, and I have a question regarding customizing a tcbox in LaTeX.
I am currently using the following LaTeX command to create a box that includes an image as a watermark:
\newcommand{\mygraphics}[2][]{%

\tcbox[enhanced,capture=minipage,boxsep=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt,left=0pt,

right=0pt,boxrule=0.4pt,drop fuzzy shadow,nobeforeafter,

colback=black!75!white,toptitle=2pt,bottomtitle=2pt,

center title,fonttitle=\small\sffamily,title=\detokenize{#2},

width=(\linewidth-4mm)/2,height=6cm,colbacktitle={black},

watermark zoom=1.0,watermark graphics={#2}]{}}

This style is based on an example from the tcolorbox manual (page 200). I would like to add the classic Mac-style three circles (red, yellow, and green) in the top-left corner of the box, just like the ones seen on macOS windows. I’ve tried to modify the command, but I’m having difficulty getting the circles to show up in the desired position.
Would anyone be able to help me modify this code to add those three circles on the top-left corner of the box, maintaining the overall styling of the tcbox?
I would greatly appreciate any assistance.
Thank you very much in advance for your time and support!
Best regards,
Mario Gómez Cano

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/609103/36296 might be a good starting point

also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/517985/36296

Did you look at the termsim package?

It would be nice to see an MWE to provide fast answers and suggestions for your problem.
I made an MWE from what I expect you are aiming at, but it is still comprehensive since I kept all of your fancy \fcbox settings. The comments of @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz are good. You can simply add colored bullets in the title of the \tcbox. I had a try on some colors for you:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{all}

\definecolor{reddish}{RGB}{255,100,90}
\definecolor{yellowish}{RGB}{255,190,40}

\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\mygraphics}[2][]{%
        \tcbox[enhanced,
               capture=minipage,
               boxsep=0pt,
               top=0pt,
               bottom=0pt,
               left=0pt,
               right=0pt,
               boxrule=0.4pt,
               drop fuzzy shadow,
               nobeforeafter,
               colback=black!75!white,
               toptitle=2pt,
               bottomtitle=2pt,
               fonttitle=\small\sffamily,
               title=~\raisebox{-0.3 em}{%
                         \textcolor{reddish}{\Huge{$\bullet$}}%
                         \textcolor{yellowish}{\Huge{$\bullet$}}%
                         \textcolor{gray}{\Huge{$\bullet$}}%
                     }%
                     ~\detokenize{#2},
               width=(\linewidth-4mm)/2,
               height=6cm,
               colbacktitle={black},
               watermark zoom=1.0,
               watermark graphics={#2}]
               {}
    }
    \mygraphics{example-image}
\end{document}



Hi,
Thank you so much for your response—it has helped me tremendously! Your guidance clarified the issue I was struggling with, and I was able to resolve it thanks to your advice.
I truly appreciate the time and effort you took to provide such a detailed and helpful explanation.
Best regards,
Mario Gómez Cano
